# How to get VBA code out of an old xls file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with opening an old excel file with VBA macros. It looks like some of the VBa libraries are no longer used in excel 365.
While opening I get an error:

Opening the VBA project in this file requires a component that is not currently installed. This file will be opened without the VBA project. Fro more information, search Office.com for "VBA converters"

I struggle to install those libraries on my PC, but in the meantime I wonder if there is any workaround to get the VBA code out of this file.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I attached mentioned file.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1msKl4kZANwwOTcqkDDb6pUjaaYkZ57lS/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=105093812803215551016&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Can you attach the file to have a look?

Comment: Hi, I added link to google drive.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem when install office2003 and save it to microsoft office excel workbook(*.xls)

[Link for office 2003](https://files.myegy.space/166/4/M_O2003F_En.iso)

[Your file after convert](https://linksharing.samsungcloud.com/5AF1oymc68Eo)

Thanks for Mr.Yasserkhalil