# How can I extract old VBA macros without excel?

Tags: excel, vba, type-conversion, office365

I have an old excel file that contains a model coded using VBA.

I need that model but I only have access to Office365 which is not compatible. When I open the xls file containing the VBA code it gives the warning:

"Opening the VBA project in this file requires a component that is not currently installed. This file will be opened without the VBA project. For more information, search Office.com for "VBA Converters"."

I've scoured the internet trying to find one of these converters with no luck. It is my work computer so I cannot install an old version of excel, or modify the current installation.

Is there ANY way to simply just view the VBA code - I do not need to be able to run it, Ideally if I could even just print it out as plain text that would be fine.

I have access to python if that helps.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've used online converters to try to convert the xls file to xlsm, no luck.
- I've tried reading the files with Pandas, and with ZipFile, no luck
- I've tried just reading it in a text editor but it's obviously a binary code so that was a useless attempt.

I cannot seem to find any useful advice in forum posts hence this post.

Comment: Give the file to someone else who can read the VBA?

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://www.decalage.info/vba_tools)? I have not tested it so I am not sure if it works but the logic explained there makes sense...

Comment: @SiddharthRout - good find.  I remember trying that out, and I think it did work...

Comment: Office 365 can open xls workbooks. I am not sure what you are asking. If you are trying to open the xls workbook from web based excel you will have the problem you describe. Office 365 can be opened from the desktop though so you should be able to open the xls file.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Oh that's nice. The link is now bookmarked! Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @Tom. If you are unable to extract the code, feel free to share the file. I am willing to give it a look. (*Provided it is not password protected and if it is password protected, then do share the password*)

Comment: @Davesexcel There are certain xls files which will give you the error in Office 365 as well. You need convertors for it. [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71121229/how-to-get-vba-code-out-of-an-old-xls-file) is one such example. Check out the file in the question. It will give you the same error in Office 365. Many years ago there was a hotfix (kb-926430) which you could install but that is not available anymore. I have Office 2003 in a VM, I can try opening the file.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - I tried the python extractor on the sample workbook you linked, and it was unable to extract any code.

Comment: @TimWilliams: I just opened the file in MSOFFICE 2003 in VM and I was able to see the VBA code.

Comment: @Tom: Like I mentioned earlier, I can check your file as well if you wish

Comment: @SiddharthRout Thanks for the suggestion I'll give that website a try!

Comment: @Davesexcel the file opens in excel, I can see the data, but it's stripped all the VB code, it isn't anywhere in the file or accessible in any way.

Comment: @Tom, would it ok to share the file?

Comment: @SiddharthRout unfortunately I don't think I can share it due to confidentiality concerns, which makes getting help a tad more difficult

Comment: FYI the contents of the missing hotfix kb-926430 are linked from here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/vba-converter/m-p/2157185    Direct link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xg7oJw6fKBb2rMde6kGZ0L7DvFzVZb0/view?pli=1

Comment: I just tested that update linked in my previous comment - I was able to view the macros in the example "g203.xls" file.  I used excel 2010 because I wasn't able to find the location for the VBA dll in Office 365...

Comment: @TimWilliams: Now my turn to say "Good Find!" :)

Comment: ...and can confirm also works in Office 365 once you can find the VBA dll location (on my PC at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA)

Answer (score 2):

There is a now-unavailable "hotfix" which was published for older versions of Office which allowed you to open and view files with older-format macros.

Someone has made the content available here:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/17xg7oJw6fKBb2rMde6kGZ0L7DvFzVZb0/view?pli=1

I found that linked from this post:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/vba-converter/m-p/2157185

I followed the instructions in the readme file, and it worked for me in Office 365.  The only tricky part was locating the VBA dll folder - for me it was
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\VBA`

Comment: Helpful research +:)

Comment: Yup. nicely done!